# How to downcast in F# while ignoring the generic types?

Tags: .net-core, f#, graphql, entity-framework-core

Consider the following code with downcasting:

```
let list = [1; 2; 4] :> obj

// Successful
let list2 = list :?> int list

// Exception - System.InvalidCastException
let list3 = list :?> obj list
let list4 = list :?> _ list
```

Basically I want to **downcast** to a `list` collection but really **ignore** the `generic` type argument. However, it throws `InvalidCastException` exception for `list3` and `list4`. Is there a way to achieve this?

As a context, I am trying to accept list of Linq expression for eager fetching from `DBContext` like this to address N+1 select problem for dependent entities within GraphQL queries. I cannot really downcast to a specific type. The expression must be downcasted to a generic version `Expression<Func<Tenant,_>>` within the loop:

```
let getTenants (db: Context) takeItems skipItems =


    let expr1 =
        <@ Func<_, _>(fun x -> x.TenantConfig) @>
        |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression


    let expr2 =
        <@ Func<_, _>(fun x -> x.Invitations) @>
        |> LeafExpressionConverter.QuotationToExpression

    // This list of includes expressions will be passed by the caller eventually
    let exprs = [expr1; expr2]


    let q =
        List.fold
            (fun (acc: IQueryable<Tenant>) (x: Expression) ->
                let expr = x :?> Expression<Func<Tenant, _>>
                acc.Include(expr) :> IQueryable<Tenant>)
            (db.Tenant.AsQueryable())
            exprs

    query {
        for tenant in q do
            skip skipItems
            take takeItems
            select tenant
    }
    |> fun x -> x.ToListAsync()
    |> Async.AwaitTask
    |> Async.map Seq.toList
```

I can use the string based version of `IQueryable<'a>.Include` but that tosses the type-safety completely out of window

Comment: just dealing with the downcasting, F# does not support covariance (C# does), e.g. you believe a list<int> value supports the list<obj> interface because int supports obj. In F# you would have to "map" the elements of the list to an obj.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd That's a bummer. Any way to bypass or address the above problem? Some sort of partial type matching or anything else?

Comment: you either map, or "cast"...look up "contravariance f#"...I'll read the rest of your question to see if I can help

Comment: can you pass the expressions in 1 by 1, then you don't need some common type.

Comment: @MrDatKookerellaLtd Expressions are unknown and created dynamically as I traverse the incoming GraphQL query. I flatten that tree to the a list of includes. This mapping in happening in BAL layer while the function - `getTenants` is in DAL layer.

Comment: I'm not sure I can help in the specific context, sorry...you're doing stuff that I'm not really familar with.

Comment: this sort of reminds me of existential types....lets not do existentials...but broadly you can hide the return type inside a type that wraps the expression, and it implements a method on that does the "include"..allowing u to create a list of expressions with that type.